# How is Spring MVC different from Spring Web Flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have to build the online ecommerce website using Java. As I want to use AJAX libraries like jQuery/prototupe/moottols, someone told me to go for Request/action based frameworks as I am from web development background.

So i started learing Spring. I have done Spring DI and AOP.

Can someone please guide me that in order to reach my goal of developing ecommerce web site using spring and JQuery (same as in html pages) what thing i nned to learn

Should i go Spring MVC or web flow or they are same. i am confused.
Please help me

Also, do I need to have knowledge of servlets and JSP for Spring MVC or web flow? Someone told me not to do servlet/JSP thing as it is old.

or i have to learn that for spring MVC. i can spend 1 week on getting the basics but i am not sure what to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring MVC is a standard action-based, MVC framework.

Webflow provides extra functionality - conversations. That is useful for wizard-like flows.

Comment: it means i have to learn first MVC and then webflow or only MVC is enough. Can build ecommerce website in MVC only without flow

Comment: @Name - you can. Webflow is an extra.

Comment: are both linked to each other or i can completely follow Weflow without MVC

Comment: as I said - webflow is ontop of MVC. So I don't think you can use it without it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that web-flow is build on top of the MVC, if you look at the requirments [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.M1/reference/html/introduction.html#system-requirements), it only depends on spring core lib

Comment: I'll investigate and fix my answer. I think it used to depend on MVC a couple of years ago

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting an old thread for good reason, and maybe this will help someone else.

Since the OP was building an eCommerce site, then flow is important... select item, place in cart, go find more junk, place in cart, review cart, delete some junk you don't really need, search some more, add junk, review cart, go to checkout, change mind and go get other stuff... finally get to checkout and pay.  All of this is more easily handled in weblow than in mvc.